# How to set value in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't set an atribute in my model project.

My code is:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :eval %><br>

<% f.collection_select( :eval_was, User.all, :id, :nombre , {:prompt => "Please Select a Eval"}, {:multiple => true}) %>
</div>
```

and `eval` isn't saved in the database.

`eval` is an integer.

Does anyone know how to solve this or has somebody had the same problem?

Comment: I haven't gone to the code to verify this, but I suspect the problem is that you named your attribute 'eval'. In Ruby, `eval` is a module method of the `Kernel` module, which is included into `Object`, so, every object in Ruby already has a (private) method named 'eval'. Rails produces methods named after your attributes, but I don't believe it overrides methods that already exist. I'm leaving this as a comment rather than an answer because I'm not in a position to verify my suspicion at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your collection select is for the field `eval_was` instead of `eval`.

Try this instead:

`<% f.collection_select( :eval, User.all, :id, :nombre , {:prompt => "Please Select a Eval"}, {:multiple => true}) %>`